# Why is this 2D array filtering not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, boolean-expression

I have this 2D array and I'm trying to filter it, but it's coming out unfiltered:

Data:

```
[
 ["Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #"],
 ["SO-000379-001A-047-1","SO-000379-001A-047-2","-","-","-"]
]
```

Filtering line:

```
cads = cads.filter(e => e[1] != "-" || e[1] != '');
```

Expected result:

```
[
 ["Val #","Val #"],
 ["SO-000379-001A-047-1","SO-000379-001A-047-2"]
]
```

WTHeck am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [
 ["Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #"],
 ["SO-000379-001A-047-1","SO-000379-001A-047-2","-","-","-"]
]

for (let i = 0; i <= data[1].length; i++) {
    if(data[1][i] === "-"){
        data[0].splice(i,1);
        data[1].splice(i,1);
        i--;
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

Not smart enough to use those Array.map/filter function, but I guess this is what you want?

Comment: Pretty straight forward! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```js
const data = [
 ["Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #"],
 ["SO-000379-001A-047-1","SO-000379-001A-047-2","-","-","-"]
]

const result = data.map(d => d.filter(v => !['', '-'].includes(v)))

console.log(result)
```

you want to filter out the inner arrays not the main one

so you have to map each external array and then filter the single rows

Comment: Hi! Thanks for jumping in. This is returning all "Val #" and only filtered "SO" values... Shouldn't this be only 2 Val # as well?

Comment: Sorry! I should have added the expected result and I just did it. Thank you!

Comment: Why only 2 "Val #" there are 5 in the array? Did you mean there is a 1 to 1 relationship between row 1 and row 2 and if row 2 is "-" the row 1 value should be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need? Filter items based on x and y axis.

```js
const cads = [
  ["Val #", "Val #", "Val #3", "Val #", "Val #"],
  ["SO-000379-001A-047-1", "-", "SO-000379-001A-047-2", "-", "-"]
]

function f(data) {
  if (!(data && data.length)) {
    return []
  }
  const v = []
  const m = data.length;
  const n = data[0].length;
  const check = (x) => x !== '-' && x !== ''
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let f = true
    for (let j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (!check(data[j][i])) {
        f = false
        break;
      }
    }
    if (f) {
      for (let k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        v[k] = v[k] || []
        v[k].push(data[k][i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return v
}
console.log(f(cads))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Lots for me to learn here!

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

I believe what you are looking for is a way to filter both rows of the array based on the items in the second row.  Here is an example of how to do that.  I changed your data slightly to show that it is filtering row 1.

**Script**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let data = [ ["Val 1","Val 2","Val 3","Val 4","Val 5"],
                  ["SO-000379-001A-047-1","","SO-000379-001A-047-2","-","-"] ];
    let result = [[],[]];
    data[1].forEach( (item,i) => {
      if( (item != "-") && (item != "") ) {
        result[0].push(data[0][i]);
        result[1].push(data[1][i]);
      }
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
8:23:57 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:23:58 AM  Info    [ [ 'Val 1', 'Val 3' ],
  [ 'SO-000379-001A-047-1', 'SO-000379-001A-047-2' ] ]
8:23:57 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from the question what you are trying to achieve. The following script is the simplest way since the latest ECMA to filter such a nested array. The criteria I used here is to filter out strings that only contain `"-"` but you can modify it to add/remove other criteria.

```
let array = [
     ["Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #","Val #"],
     ["SO-000379-001A-047-1","SO-000379-001A-047-2","-","-","-"]
     ]
let filtered = [];
for (e of array) {
  let kept = [];
  for (item of e) {
    if (item != "-") kept.push(item);
  }
  filtered.push(kept);
}
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for sharing! The proposed solution above doesn't filter the "Val #". Sorry if I wasn't that clear in my question.

Comment: What are you trying to filter here? Only the first two values of each array?